# Configuring an editor for various languages using Factory Method Pattern

Tags: java, object-oriented, factory-method

I need to know if my code is a valid implementation of the factory method pattern. Also, if the Configuration and Editor were interfaces would this still be a valid implementation of the Factory Pattern?

```
public abstract class Configuration {

    protected List<String> keyWords;

    abstract void getTheme();
    abstract String getKeyWords();
}
```

```
public abstract class Editor {

    public final void useEditor() {
        Configuration configuration = createConfiguration();
        configuration.getTheme();
        parse(configuration.getKeyWords());
        save();
    }

    //The Factory Method
    public abstract Configuration createConfiguration();

    public abstract void parse(String sourceCode);

    public void save() {
        System.out.println("The file was saved..");
    }
}
```

```
public class JavaConfiguration extends Configuration {
    public JavaConfiguration() {
        keyWords = new ArrayList<>();
        keyWords.add("class");
        keyWords.add("protected");
    }

    @Override
    void getTheme() {
        System.out.println("Applied Java Theme...");
    }

    @Override
    String getKeyWords() {
        return keyWords.toString();
    }
}
```

```
public class PythonConfiguration extends Configuration {

    public PythonConfiguration() {
        keyWords = new ArrayList<>();
        keyWords.add("def");
        keyWords.add("print");
    }

    @Override
    void getTheme() {
        System.out.println("Applied Python Theme...");
    }

    @Override
    String getKeyWords() {
        return keyWords.toString();
    }
}
```

```
public class JavaEditor extends Editor {
    @Override
    public Configuration createConfiguration() {
        return new JavaConfiguration();
    }

    @Override
    public void parse(String sourceCode) {
        System.out.println("Parsing Java code...");
    }
}
```

```
public class PythonEditor extends Editor {

    @Override
    public Configuration createConfiguration() {
        return new PythonConfiguration();
    }

    @Override
    public void parse(String sourceCode) {
        System.out.println("Parsing python code...");
    }
}
```

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String language = sc.next();
        Editor editor = createEditor(language);
        editor.useEditor();
    }

    private static Editor createEditor(String language) {
        switch(language) {
            case "Java":
                return new JavaEditor();
            case "Python":
                return new PythonEditor();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: It seems that the Factory Method Pattern is not the appropriate design pattern to use in this case, as suggested by @200_success and @Timothy Truckle. A simple Editor class which receives a Configuration as a parameter should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to know if my code is a valid implementation of the factory method pattern.

No.

The reason is that the *factory* cannot be part of the objects to be created. I think you would be surprised to find a factory in the the hedge of your car, wouldn't you?

Generally spoken your approach fails the *Separation of Concerns* principle.

You have two responsibilities in your code that belong to a *factory*:

1. identifying the requested type.
2. creating the actual object.

Both should be in a separate factory class.

---

Also: your "factory" is producing the wrong type of objects because of your misconception of inheritance.

We employ inheritance when the child classes differ in *behavior*. But your `Editor` extensions only differ in *configuration* (as far as your code example is showing...).

So what your (yet to build) factory should do is creating the "language depended"  key word list and pass that into a new instance of the one and only `Editor` class.

Answer (score 2):

The `getKeyWords()` method is not particularly useful.  It takes a `List<String>` and summarizes its contents in a degraded form.  It's particularly inappropriate for `Editor.useEditor()` to attempt to parse this undocumented string representation.  I would prefer to have it return an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-).  The `JavaConfiguration` class would be better written as

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class JavaConfiguration extends Configuration {
    private static List<> KEYWORDS = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
        "class",
        "protected"
    ));

    @Override
    List<String> getKeywords() {
        return KEYWORDS;
    }

    …
}
```

Does the order of the keywords matter?  Perhaps a `Set` would be more appropriate than a `List`.

---

Typically, you wouldn't want to have the `App` be responsible for performing the translation from language name to the associated `Configuration` object.

```
public abstract class Configuration {
    abstract void getTheme();
    abstract List<String> getKeywords();

    public static Configuration forLanguage(String language) {
        switch (language) {
            case "Java":
                …
        }
    }
}
```

A factory might not be the most appropriate pattern, though, since there isn't any point in instantiating many copies of each `Configuration` subclass.  Reusing singletons might be better.

---

One would hope that the whole point of having various `Configuration`s is to contain all the language-specific behaviours of the `Editor`.  Therefore, if the system is designed properly, then there should only be one `Editor` class, whose constructor accepts a `Configuration`.  (I'm assuming that you don't need the `Editor` to be able to switch languages on the fly.)